# How do I get the closest approach to a number?

Tags: lua

So, I've been wondering how to get the closest approach to a number with a given two numbers (this might be hard to understand at first, so I'll give a example)

*Examples:*

***1.*** ***Number 4 needs to be divisible by 5, but since it isn't, we need to get the closest approach. In this ocassion, the closest approach would be 5.***

***2. A grid system defines if the position marked(0,52.4) is divisible by a number(5, which is grid size). Thing is, it needs to find the closest approach to the grid size(5). It will use given number, and given grid size. So like, Position marked: (5.85,52.4), Grid size: 5, Closest approach: (5,50)***

***3. Number 93.594664 needs to be divisible by 9, but it isn't exactly 90 or 9. So, the closest approach here would be 90. How do I get this number?***

I've already tryed everything I could. Nothing seems to work.
If anyone knows how to do this, please comment.

Comment: `math.floor(n/d + 0.5) * d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function closest(n, d) -- n Number, d Divisible by
    local remainder = n % d
    local c -- closest

    if remainder >= (d / 2) then
        c = (n + (d - remainder))
    else
        c = (n - remainder)
    end

    print(c)
end
```

Then:

```
closest(4, 5) -- prints 5
closest(5.85, 5) -- prints 5
closest(52.4, 5) -- prints 50
closest(93.594664, 9) -- prints 90
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been a lot asking myself how to do that. Your comment is really helpful to my project.